# VSCode からプログラムを実行できません

Tags: vscode

macでプログラミングを始めたものです。エディタにVScodeが良いと書いてあったのでインストールしましたが、不明な点がいくつかあります。お答えいただけると嬉しいです。

まず、実行ができません。実行と押すと、「環境の選択」と出てきてどれを押しても無反応です。いえ、一番上のChromeというやつを押すと

```js
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Tomorrow Night Blue"
}
```

とだけ別のタブに表示されます。これはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

今まではIDLEを使っていました。素朴でしたが、シンプルで使いやすかったです。
VS codeもそうだと思っていたのですが、

毎回「実行→デバッグするかどうかの選択→実行環境の選択」と何度も操作するのは面倒です。
これらを簡潔にワンタッチでする方法も知りたいです。よろしくお願いします

Comment: IDLEを使っていらしたということは、pythonのコーディングをしたいのかと思います。私はvscodeでc++のコーディングしかしたことがありませんが、使いこなすのはけっこう難しかったです。本家の英文のドキュメントをたくさん読みました。英語が苦手でなかったら本家のpythonのチュートリアルを読むのが近道だと思います。 https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDLEを使っていたということなので、Pythonでプログラミングしていたのでしょうか。

VS Codeは拡張機能でPythonの環境を構築するので、まずPythonの拡張機能が必要です。
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

VS Codeの拡張機能(Ctrl+Shift+X)から`Python`をインストールします。

VS Codeの実行(Ctrl+Shift+D)から`launch.json`を作成する。
Python > Python File で下記のようなファイルが作成されます。

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

`launch.json`が作成出来たら、VS Codeの実行から実行のボタンや`F5`のショートカットで実行できます。